# jre install directory oddness

Tags: java, windows, installation

Here's something weird.

Consider these two recent versions of the java environment:

```
jre-8u11-windows-i586.exe
jre-8u20-windows-i586.exe
```

Install 8u11.  It will place it into program files (x86)\java\jre8

Install 8u20.  It will place it into program files (x86)\java\jre1.8.0_20

I don't know exactly when the naming changed between rev 11 and rev 20 but it's kind of annoying seeing that I need to have JAVA_HOME preset in a config file (for a windows service that will be installed after).  Used to be that any earlier rev of java 1.8 would install to the jre8 folder... not any longer it seems.  Why would this change?

Comment: You can configure installation path while setup

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  My point is, the default directory has been X for a while, then changed to Y... wondering why that was?  It makes a difference when you have a second install package that is expecting the program to be found in X... and the folks installing all of this software are going to simply accept the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle switched to a different installer.

As always such big changes have side effects. The fact that the path now includes the full version number could well be completely unintentionally.

Hint: You could extract the path from the registry (this example is for 32bit windows)

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\1.8]
"JavaHome"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_20"
```

Regarding the installer changes: While the installer is still an installer.exe inside an msi inside an installer.exe, many things were changed and some improved. For example the msi is now self-contained (no separate cab archive for files, no separate mst file for translations to other languages, the translations now also affects the main menu entries).

However the old msi could be extracted with 7zip, the new one has an empty file table, just the two binaries installerexe and uninstallerexe.

These are just some visible symptoms, internally there must be more changes.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has been attempting to implement a rule set file to tackle the issues inherent to the Java product family; Namely, it's ability to work with other versions of itself. The rule set requires a specific version that looks like jre1.8.0_20 so they can intercept calls for that specific version. Using a name like jre8 would not be able to get specific enough for a the rule.

To make matters worse, a change like this is a major change yet they put it in a minor release. Many companies have been caught off-guard with these types of implementations.